# Result array persists after using back button

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have a search bar `ion-searchbar` and when I search I store the results in a promise array. The issue I'm facing is when I search and then use the back button--my results remain in the array from the previous search.

The only way to empty my array is to do a full page reload otherwise the array will keep appending results instead of emptying it.

[Initial results page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yPoTt.png)

[Hitting back button and searching again](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S0jgF.png)

From my search service it returns a promise object array: `Promise<GetSearchResults[]>`

My `GetSearchResults` object looks like so:

```
export interface GetSearchResults {
  title: string;
  id: string;
}
```

On my `Search Page` I have:

```
export class SearchPage implements OnInit {
  query: string;
  results: Promise<GetSearchResults[]>;

  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private search: SearchQueryService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.paramMap.subscribe(async (params) => {
      this.query = params.get('query');

      console.log('Params -> ' + JSON.stringify(params));
      if (this.query != null) {
        console.log('Query => ' + this.query);
        this.results = this.search.searchPages(this.query);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

The issue I'm facing is each router navigation to my search page:
`this.router.navigate(['/search', this.query]);`

The search page's array does not start with an empty results array if it was previously set.

`this.results = this.search.searchPages(this.query);` <- this array keeps appending results and isn't empty unless the page is completely reloaded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just remove your results on ionViewDidLeave or ionViewWillEnter
read more about Ionic page events [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/angular/lifecycle)